# Angular 2 cannot find name zingchart

Tags: angular, typescript, zingchart

I have been following this tutorial https://scotch.io/tutorials/interactive-angular-2-charts-with-zingchart to add zingchart to my angular 2 project. But i get the error cannot find name zingchart when creating the zingchart component

``

```
   export class ZingChart implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {  
          chart: Chart

          constructor (private zone: NgZone) { }

          ngAfterViewInit () {
            this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => zingchart.render(this.chart));
          }

          ngOnDestroy () {
            zingchart.exec(this.chart.id, 'destroy');
          }
   }
```

``

Comment: Did you add zingchart as a script reference?

Comment: yes i did, am using the laravel framework, so i added it using the blade html helper {{Html::script("assets/js/zingchart.min.js")}}. Found the solution from this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40820327/how-do-i-implement-zingchart-into-angular2?answertab=active#tab-top .  I had to declare a variable ...                                                                             declare var zingchart: any;

Comment: That post is relative to rc4 and rc5. Check this [follow up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40820327/how-do-i-implement-zingchart-into-angular2)